# Integration of Angular JS in Spring web project leads to it taking forever to publish a project to Tomcat

Tags: angularjs, eclipse, spring, tomcat

After I integrated Angular JS into my Spring web application it is taking forever , for the project to get published to Tomcat. I have increased my Tomcat heap space to 1024M . How do I fix this ? [image]

[image]

Comment: What version of Java are you using?

Comment: The Java version I am using is 1.7

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using Java 1.7 (< than 8, which no longer uses PermGen space), you can set the maxPermSize, which I would bet helps you in this situation. Often, frameworks like Spring (using CGLib) and other scripting languages like Groovy make heavy use of dynamic class creation, which are stored in the PermGen space.

Try setting the maxPermSize like this and see if it helps:

```
java -Xms128m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m ...
```

If you are in an IDE, you would want to set this as part of your VM Options.